# CriteriaAPI Query with Join by a string value

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

I have currently a query with a bunch of filters, which makes sense to use the Criteria API, unfortunately I have this query that uses a Join which uses a string value instead of a relationship. This is an example of the query:

```
SELECT ua.id,
   COALESCE(uf.status, f.status) AS status,
   r.name,
   ua.companyname,
   ua.firstname,
   ua.lastname,
   ua.usergroup,
   ua.email,
   ua.country,
   ua.continent
 FROM useraccount ua
     JOIN userrole ur on ua.id = ur.userid
     JOIN role r on ur.roleid = r.id and r.eventgroupid = 1
     JOIN feature f on f.name = 'Locked'
     LEFT JOIN userfeature uf on uf.featureid = f.id AND uf.userid = ua.id;
```

As you can see the problem of the query is that I want to use COALESCE operation to get a UserFeature status if present, if not use the default status from the Feature table.

The feature table is just a simple one with id, name and the status, it is only related to UserFeature and UserFeature at the same time is related to the UserAccount.

As you might guess the CriteriaAPi doesn't allows a Join<> by a regular string value. I have tried to get my mind around to get how can I change the select statement to be more aligned with what CriteriaAPI offers, but I haven't found anything on this.

I'm using PostgreSQL and Hibernate 5.4.32 (by using the spring starter jpa)

Comment: wouldn't "LEFT JOIN userfeature uf on uf.userid = ua.id JOIN  feature f on uf.featureid = f.id AND f.name = 'Locked' " make sense too, allowing you to go from UserRole to UserFeature then to Feature. UserFeature seems like it should have a relational mapping to Feature using featureid as the foreign key column that you could be using in addition to the LOCKED name.

Comment: No, just tried but it doesn't give me what I'm expecting. The gist of it is basically that not all Users are on the UserFeature table, there are some which will have the UserFeature status NULL and I need that null to be covered by the default feature which is this feature that has the name 'Locked', by relating to UserFeature and Feature by Id, it will return only the ones that are there, but I need also the users that are not in the UserFeature table.